# Swift4: How to resolve "Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound"? (duration time delay in UI)

Tags: ios, swift, time, swift4, fatal-error

I try to close the menu animatedly using animation, 
I decided to reduce the size of the `UIScrollView` on button press when size reduces up to my desired value, then I hide it.

to accomplish the task according to my desired user interface at some points, I had used the "time delay function" (300 milisec given)

everything goes well: if I don't press the button again and again until time limit reached

Error occurred: when i press button again and again before  with in 300 milisec

```
func disAppearBlanceMenu(){
    let x1 = btn_addBalance.clickableimg.frame.midX
    let y1 = btn_addBalance.clickableimg.frame.maxY

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.BalanceMenu.scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: x1 - 150, y: y1 + 20, width: 200, height: 20)
    }
    time.delay(milliSec: 300) {
        self.BalanceMenu.triangle.isHidden = true
        self.BalanceMenu.scrollview.isHidden = true
        for i in 0...(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count - 1) {
            self.BalanceMenuBtn[i].imag.removeFromSuperview()
            self.BalanceMenuBtn[i].button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.BalanceMenuBtn.removeAll()

    }
    displayBalanceMenu = true
}
```

Where

```
class time {
    static func delay(milliSec:Int, code: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(milliSec)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
            code()
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs here:

```
time.delay(milliSec: 300) {
```

It says

> 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound'

Comment: why simply not disabling pressing the button during the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you should add a condition before executing the for loop like this :

```
time.delay(milliSec: 300) {
            self.BalanceMenu.triangle.isHidden = true
            self.BalanceMenu.scrollview.isHidden = true
       if self.BalanceMenuBtn.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count - 1) {
                self.BalanceMenuBtn[i].imag.removeFromSuperview()
                self.BalanceMenuBtn[i].button.removeFromSuperview()
            }
           self.BalanceMenuBtn.removeAll()
       }
    }
```

You get this error when in for loop the lower bound is greater than the upper bound. In your code, when the first time the animation is completed then the count of the array will be 0 and for second time the condition would be like this

```
for I in 0...-1
```

That is why you are getting a crash and by checking the condition of the count as shown in my answer this would not crash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: problem is not with delay function .... Fatal error occurs because of condition in delay function ...

for i in 0...(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count - 1) i changed it to for i in 0..<(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count)  now it's working well ... can u please explain why that for loop condition cause this fatal error

Comment: Updated my answer. With your comment also your crash will be fixed cause it would be executed as 'for i in 0..<0'. So that is not going to crash. Let me know if this is still unclear.

Comment: `guard statement` saves my day

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something when the animation is done. If so, use its `completion` parameter:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
    self.BalanceMenu.scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: x1 - 150, y: y1 + 20, width: 200, height: 20)
}, completion: { _ in
    self.BalanceMenu.triangle.isHidden = true
    self.BalanceMenu.scrollview.isHidden = true
    for button in self.BalanceMenuBtn {
        button.imag.removeFromSuperview()
        button.button.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    self.BalanceMenuBtn.removeAll()
})
```

It avoids timing problems introduced by that `delay` method. It also makes the intent more explicit.

---

Needless to say, once you get this immediate issue behind you, the properties `BalanceMenu` and `BalanceMenuBtn` should be renamed to start with lowercase letters, e.g., maybe `balanceMenu` and `balanceMenuButtons`, respectively. Also note the use of `Buttons` suffix rather than `Btn`, to make it clear it’s an array of buttons.

Comment: problem is not with delay function .... Fatal error occurs because of condition in delay function ... 'for i in 0...(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count - 1)' i changed it to 'for i in 0..<(self.BalanceMenuBtn.count)' now it's working well ... can u please explain why that for loop condition cause this fatal error

Comment: If `BalanceMenuBtn` is empty, the former translates to `for i in 0...-1 {…}` (which causes the error you describe), whereas the latter results in `for i in 0..<0 {…}` (which translates to “do nothing”, which is fine). You still don’t want to use that `delay` pattern, though.